# What stops me from copying a signature signed on a signature pad?

Tags: encryption, digital-signature

There are a lot of electronic signature pads/devices in use these days, from couriers to banks. Let's say I just signed a PDF document on someone else's signature pad. What stops the owner from technically copying the signature to another document and saying that I signed the latter, not the first document?

Comment: Intresting question. I would say that it's impossible to be sure that this doesn't occur. Forging signatures isn't really a new issue, it's been around for quite some time.

Comment: Yes, but you can't copy-paste my signature on a piece of paper, it wouldn't pass a forensic test.

Comment: I like the question, but you might get better answers on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm guessing there's some private key hidden somewhere in each device which isn't easily recoverable (at least not without melting the chip)... but maybe someone could clarify this a bit.

Comment: In most cases your guess would be wrong. I've seen couriers' websites on which it is possible to view the signature as a bitmap, and it would be quite easy to scrape the image from the website and paste it into a document as a signature. If that document were then (say) sent as a fax it would be accepted as a signed document for legal purposes. As with any handwritten signature, it would be treated as valid unless contested by the purported signer. Fortunately most of these devices make such low quality scans that the signatures are usually implausible as written signatures.

Comment: I dug into this question again and found an EU directive (1999/93), that states the requirements for an advanced digital signature, which says that:
(b) the signature-creation-data used for signature generation cannot, with reasonable assurance, be derived and the signature is protected against forgery using currently available technology; From here on I stumbled upon some devices that actually have an unique private key inserted during production... http://www.mymusa.eu/upload/0/st/stepoverinfosfrbetreibervonesignaturenen.pdf

Comment: Created security.stackexchange.com question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23387/which-factors-should-i-consider-for-devices-that-accept-handwritten-digital-sign

Answer (score 0):

I made a short screen cast to explain that 'just adding a drawing' isn't sufficient to 'sign' a PDF: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYK45lhLr8I&list=UUqMYqMmYW0k2BRya20LY7lw

If a 'wet ink signature' look-alike is added to a document *without* any real digital signature (involving a private/public key pair owned by the signer), a document shouldn't have any legal value. Unfortunately, some countries/states are less demanding and accept signatures that could be forged.

I'm not that happy with my screen cast anymore because I made it too controversial. I made it to make some publicity for these white papers:

- Technical aspects: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/
- Legal aspects: http://www.mnhs.org/preserve/records/legislativerecords/docs_pdfs/CA_Authentication_WhitePaper_Dec2011.pdf

Comment: I'm more interested about the signature pads/devices, that belong to the other party (e.g the bank).

Comment: To be safe, the person who signs the document, should encrypt a has of the document bytes using his personal private key (for instance: the key available on his eID, CAC or a personal USB stick). Without such a private key, the requirement of 'non-repudation' is difficult to meet. If the pad/device contains a private key that is used for different people, you could guarantee the integrity of the document and the data it contains, but the signer can always claim that somebody else signed the document (you'd need to add some biometrics to avoid this).